# Screen distortion with win forms csharp for 64 bit

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, splitcontainer

I have used a split container inside Tabpage. It's working fine everywhere except for a laptop which has win7 i5. We checked in other win 7 laptops but works fine. 
The problem is when we restore the Window and maximize it the split container does not resize leaving a blank space.

I just figured out what the problem may be :
 1. the problem is with 64 - bit machines 
 2. resize event of tab control is not getting called. 
 3. I have explicitly resized it on the mdi form and the problem seems to be solved but . it takes time and the resizing can be seen. it should be seamless.
 4. Its a temporary solution. Plz help on it

Comment: Can you show the code you use for your split container? Maybe it will be helpful for people trying to help you.

Comment: splitContainer is added at design time so should i post the code from designer.cs 
Also for better clarity I have 3 tabpages each tab page contains a similar split container and each split container contains a tablelayoutpanel.
i have tried autosize,dock, coding on resize event to maximize window.

Comment: I just figured out what the problem may be :
1. the problem is with 64 - bit machines
2. resize event of tab control is not getting called.
3. I have explicitly resized it on the mdi form and the problem seems to be solved but . it takes time and the resizing can be seen. it should be seamless.
4. Its a temporary solution. Plz help on it.

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution the problem was not with any container or control.
It is a limitation of 64 bit machines. If we have deeply nested controls the resize event of the deepest children are not called normally if you are 15-16 levels deep. For that we need to override the OnSizeChanged event of some forms or control.
refer this site if any one is facing the same problem 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f06b8980-a38d-441f-8a5d-aa28c52f60c0/nested-usercontrols-on-x64-resizing-problem